# Vector Laplacian in Curved Spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, tensors, laplacian, general-relativity

The vector gradient, $\mathbb{L}$, is defined as

$$
(\mathbb{L} W)^{ij} \equiv \nabla^{i} W^{j} + \nabla^{j} W^{i} - \frac{2}{3} g^{ij} \nabla_{k} W^{k} \,,
$$

where $\nabla_{i}$ is the covariant derivative compatible with the metric $g_{ij}$.

Now, the vector Laplacian, $\Delta_{\mathbb L}$, is define as:

$$
(\Delta_{\mathbb L} W)^{i} \equiv \nabla_{j} (\mathbb{L} W)^{ij} \,.
$$

When I expand the above definition, I get:

\begin{align}
(\Delta_{\mathbb L} W)^{i} &\equiv \nabla_{j} (\mathbb{L} W)^{ij} \\
&= \nabla_{j} \left( \nabla^{i} W^{j} + \nabla^{j} W^{i} - \frac{2}{3} g^{ij} \nabla_{k} W^{k} \right) \\
&= \nabla_{j} (\nabla^{i} W^{j}) + (\nabla_{j} \nabla^{j}) W^{i} - \frac{2}{3} (g^{ij} \nabla_{j}) \nabla_{k} W^{k} \\
&= \nabla^{i} (\nabla_{j} W^{j}) + (\nabla_{j} \nabla^{j}) W^{i} - \frac{2}{3} \nabla^{i}( \nabla_{k} W^{k}) \\
&= \nabla^{2} W^{i} + \frac{1}{3} \nabla^{i} (\nabla_{j} W^{j}) \,,
\end{align}

where $\nabla^{2} \equiv \nabla_{j} \nabla^{j}$.

However, the correct expression should be:

$$
\nabla^{2} W^{i} + \frac{1}{3} \nabla^{i} (\nabla_{j} W^{j}) + R^{i}_{j} W^{j} \,,
$$

where $R^{i}_{j}$ is the Ricci tensor.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The covariant derivatives $\nabla_j$ and $\nabla^i$ do not commute. Interchanging them gives rise to the curvature term. In general we have

$$\nabla_j\nabla_iW_k - \nabla_i\nabla_jW_k = W_lR^l_{\ kij}$$

with the curvature tensor $R^l_{\ kij}$. Contracting $j$ and $k$ yields

$$\nabla_j\nabla_iW^j - \nabla_i\nabla_jW^j = W_lR^{lj}_{\ \ \ ij}$$

and hence

$$\nabla_j\nabla^iW^j = \nabla^i\nabla_jW^j + R^i_{\ j}W^j$$

from which the correct result follows.